# Session based CSRF tokens when linking from external links

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, csrf, csrf-token

I'm having an issue with CSRF tokens on externally linked pages.

I have a chat bot in whatsapp that sends a user a one-time link to the site. They click the link and need to enter a PIN on the site in order to confirm a request (we do this so the user's PIN is never saved in plain text on whatsapp).

Like all forms on the site, the PIN page has a hidden CSRF token that gets submitted too. The CSRF token is generated in part with the session id, and on submission part of the validation is checking its for the current session.

I am seeing an issue where on some submissions of the PIN page that the CSRF validation is failing due to the session id being different from the initial page load request.

My guess on what is happening is that the user has an active session with the site already (lets call that `session 001`). They later get sent the whatsapp link which they click on. It looks like sometimes the browser does not send the existing session cookie (I assume due to some tightening on the `SameSite` policy stuff), so when the user lands on the PIN page the site sees it as a new visit and creates a new `session 002`. Then on submit of the form the browser sends the original "session 001" cookie. So the token CSRF token was generated with "session 002", but validated against `session 002`.
(It's probably worth noting this is a legacy system and no SameSite policy is being explicity set)

I don't want to be logging session ids in production so I can't think of a way to verify this is actually what is happening. I haven't been able replicate this behaviour in my dev environment yet.

Does this sound like a known thing that I am just not understanding well? Any ideas on ways to work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions don't work between browser tab reloads as a conceptual model (IMO) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage. In your use-case, a session is between browser tab reloads (both by refresh, hard refresh or navigation by external link) barring reloads by 'back' button presses. So in short, you need your own session UUID generator and management. Try using UUID classes implemented in most web-server platforms.

localhost may work differently due to http stipulations, although I can't figure out why this wouldn't be reproducible in localhost.

Comment: Sorry, this is a server side rendered php application. When I talk about the session I mean the backend session with php's built in `session_start()` we're dealing with. No front end JS, just a simple html form making a POST request from the initial page load

Comment: yup and the conceptual model is literally my professional opinion, I was trying to provide reference to how session is used in web-dev world in that link. So `session_start()` somehow issues a new `session_id` if the browser tab is closed and reloaded. you may need to check how your session manager is setting the session cookie in the clients' browsers

Comment: Simply closing and opening the tab keeps the same session as the browsers sends the correct session cookie. The issue appears when the user comes from an external link like from whatsapp and no cookie is delivered. But then when the user loads the next page the original cookie is sent again. This leads to 2 valid sessions in 2 page views for the same user.

Comment: I recommend adding a translation of cookie tokens and CSRF tokens to the same session ID in that case ;)